# how to solve Keyword not supported: 'data source'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string, plesk, plesk-onyx

I uploaded my website( that is programmed with **asp.net mvc and entity framework 5**) yesterday and wrote this connection string in the `web.config` file of the host root ( control panel is plesk onyx)

I tried changing it to *SqlCLient*,Removing some tags, and so many other things but no change it return error:

> keyword not supported: 'data source'

when I remove data source it return keyword not supported 'initial catalog' and so on
thanks for your attention

```
<add name="ShopDBEntities" connectionString="Data Source=some source;initial catalog=MainDB;User ID=admin;Password=pass;integrated security=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: That's simply not a valid connection string for the provider "System.Data.EntityClient".  It's a SqlClient connection string.  Are you using EF Code-First, or EDMX Database First?  What is the _working_ connection string you use locally?

Comment: Please don't ask questions [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57286577/861716). Improve the existing question instead.